# Is it possible to access values of HTML form loaded in UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, forms, uiwebview

Requirement is to load an HTML form in UIWebView and Access the values filled in that form in Objective-C.

So I was wondering if that's even possible. If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString:] method.

Answer (score 2):

use this code..

[callJsWithObjectiveC](https://github.com/Yuyutsu/callJsWithObjectiveC)

create JS file `demo.js` and add code

```
var hello = function(str){       return str; };
```

add UIWebView => To embed JavaScript in a dummy html file and load that into the UIWebView

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<script src=\"demo.js\"></script>"  baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Here is the code to make JS call

```
NString *str=@"hi JavaScript";
NSString *function = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"hello(%@)", str];
NSString *result = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:function];
```

Now, there is one important safety tip to make this actually work: The UIWebView must actually be loaded a view. It doesn’t have to be visible, but in order for the WebKit engine to execute the JS, it must be on a view.